# .htaccess mobile cookie set

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, mobile

I just created a mobile site and realized that I wanted the users to be able to view the full desktop site.

I know there is a way to check if there is a cookie with the .htaccess file, I'm wondering if there's a way to set a cookie as well.

My code:

```
#redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.stage.sunjournal\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|iPhone|blackberry|ipad|iemobile|operamobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.stage.sunjournal.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Is there a way to set a cookie and check, so my users can access the full site from their mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can -- use `[CO]` flag to set the cookie. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.stage.sunjournal.com/$1 [L,R=302,CO=mobile:yes:m.stage.sunjournal.com:0:/]
```

Obviously, you need to adjust it to whatever cookie name/value/etc you are using.

Documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co